# how to load failingUrl in webview again?

Tags: android, webview

how to load failingUrl in webview again ??

here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView); //webview in activity_main.xml
[....] // some other codes
web.loadUrl("http://my-example-site.com");
[....] // some other codes
}
// if no network, then show error.xml with a reload button;
@Override
public void onReceivedError(final WebView view, int errorCode, String description, final String failingUrl){
setContentView(R.layout.error);
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); // Reload Button in error.xml
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
web.loadUrl(failingUrl); //this one is not working...
}
});
}
```

i want to load failingUrl again..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
@Override
public void onReceivedError(final WebView view, int errorCode, String description, final String failingUrl)
{
    setContentView(R.layout.error);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); // Reload Button in error.xml
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        web.reload();
    }
    });
}
```

you have to add this statement before initialising webview

```
web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: try using view.reload() instead of web.reload()